# Can using robust standard errors solve the problem of measurement error in dependent variable?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I have a sample in which there is measurement error in the dependent variable. I understand that the estimates would be consistent, but the standard errors would not be correct. So can using robust standard errors fix this problem?

Comment: Do you know the measurement error? Eg, is it normal w/ known variance or uniform over a known range, etc? FWIW, I'm not sure I would say, "the standard errors would not be correct".

Comment: Even if the usual estimates would be consistent,  there might be much better estimates ...